# How can static method access a object? How does it happen in threading?

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I was reading about the difference between suspend and sleep because both hold the lock and then go in suspended state.
The difference said that suspend can be called upon another thread and hence is prone to deadlock.
However sleep and notify being static in nature, can only be called upon themselves and hence a thread can only sleep itself.
Now if I try to correlate this with normal codding, I cannot call a non static method from a static method without making an object. So my question here is:

1. I am not passing the object of thread object to the sleep method. Also sleep method is static. Then how will it know which thread is to be suspended?
2. How does yield() know which thread is to be set to runnable state because it is also static in nature?

Please correct me where ever I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Thread` class is not operating within the normal bounds of the Java language.  If you lookup the source code of `Thread`, you will see it is declared:

```
public static native void sleep(long millis);
```

That `native` keyword is the clue that it's going off and doing something special in the JVM code itself.

In that native code, it can work out which thread is wanting to sleep, and make the appropriate calls to the underlying OS to make it happen.

How that happens is all specific to implementation of the JVM you are using.

Comment: actually there's nothing special about the native code in this regard. Finding out the current thread is obviously always possible - after all you're executing in it right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Sleep - suspends currently executing thread from which it is called.
2. notify is not static

   public final void notify()

3 & 4 are scheduler actions. Java docs has more clear explanation for notify and notifyAll

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Yield

```
The java.lang.Thread.yield() method causes the currently executing thread object to temporarily pause and allow  
other threads to execute.
```

So, yield just yields the intrinsic lock,its up to scheduler to decide which thread will gain from it.

Comment: That is what I want to know? How can you come to know in an static method that during the execution of which object it was called

Comment: In any case Thread.sleep(..) must be called from a Thread ( execution path). Sleep just makes the Thread which executed this piece of code to pause. Thread.sleep does not depend on which object it is called from but from which Thread this was called.

Answer (score 0):

> *I am not passing the object of thread object to the sleep method. Also sleep method is static. Then how will it know which thread is to
>   be suspended?*

`Thread.sleep()` only operates on the *current* thread. That is, the thread that calls the `sleep()` method. A thread can only cause itself to sleep; no thread can cause *another* thread to sleep.

> How does notify() know which method is to be set to runnable state
>   because it is also static in nature?

`notify` is not static. `Object.notify()` is a method on `Object`, not on `Thread`. Java internally keeps a list of threads that are *waiting* (that have called the method `Object.wait` on an object), and `notify` wakes any of the threads in this list. (There is no guarantee which one it is)

> How does notifyAll() get a list of all the threads that are running so
>   that it can put all those threads into runnable state?

`notifyAll` does not get a list of all threads; just like the `notify` method, it gets the list of all threads that are waiting *on a particular object*. `notifyAll` wakes *all* of these threads up. But only one of them will be able to continue immediately, because, after being woken up, each thread will first try to object the *monitor* on the object, and only one thread at a time can hold the monitor.

> Just to confirm:- notifyAll() will be putting only suspended threads
>   into running state and will not change the state of running threads.

No, being *suspended* is unrelated to `wait`/`notify` (It is only related to the methods `Thread.suspend` and `Thread.resume`, both of which are deprecated). Instead, notify all will wake up *waiting* threads. However, only one of these threads will be able to continue running immediately; the other threads will now wait to obtain the monitor (also known as "the lock") on the object.